# Posting useful online content from non Stack Exchange site to askubuntu

Tags: discussion

If I see some very useful post regarding Ubuntu on some non Stack Exchange site, is it alright to modify it to make it more relevant and then post it here?

Comment: Wouldn't you just end up duplicating content?

Comment: That's why I said about correcting mistakes but taking the idea in general

Comment: Then why not correct the mistakes in the original post by suggesting edits?

Comment: If you see a question and find an answer for it, it's perfectly fine to include what you think is relevant in an answer and link the source. Adapting a post as a Q&A is a little weird, and I'm not sure how well that would be accepted.

Comment: I don't know why this got downvoted so much. It is encouraged for you to add content here, there is even a set of rules for dealing with bringing in content. As long it fits the format and you uses your own words or quote just the relevant part and explain it, I see no problem with bringing in outside content. Of course do not forget to give proper attribution to the people you took it from and avoid copying whole articles word for word.

Comment: @edwinksl He is asking about `non` stack exchange sites, you are right cross posting is not allowed but bringing in new useful content is what people do here.

Comment: @MarkKirby I must have missed the `non` the first time I read it. Thanks for pointing that out.